# How to remove unnecessary wrapping in PDF, generated using JasperReports (jrxml)?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, textfield, word-wrap

I am using jasper report for generating my PDF report. I use following **textField** configuration in **jrxml** file.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="ec0e2f1f-82d6-46fd-ba68-394be7f6b015" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="16" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                        <pen lineColor="#757575"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="none">
                        <font size="11"/>
                        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
```

When export PDF, It will show me records like given in below screen-shot. See in first **record**, there is no single character in second **row**. Even though it is behaving like text wrapping. I think there must be any solution. Please help me if anybody resolved this issue.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Zj2kR4BGU5ckpXcGNvVzlseW8/edit?usp=sharing) I am giving link for whole PDF file.

[image: jasper report exported pdf file screen-sht]

Comment: What exactly is the content of the field `firstName` for that record? Are there probably any trailing white spaces? Otherwise can you provide the PDF for analysis?

Comment: my exact firstName content is **Brian Thiskasjkhh**. And Yes I can provide PDF, but I don't know how to attach PDF file in stackOverFlow :( Is is same as image file?

Comment: I added link for whole PDF file.

Comment: Ok, the PDF unfortunately does not explain the issue (I hoped to find some whitespace output on the empty line). Another idea, though, because I see that you use the built-in font Helvetica in the PDF: If you preview the result in iReport in a different format (e.g. the internal one), do you see a different font used causing the line to break? (Helvetica in JR report PDF export often means some font mismatch.)

Comment: I don't think its font issue..and also I didn't change font..Its default one already

Comment: Have you at least checked whether it looks different in the internal preview? *Its default one* - that might be the problem because in that case PDF generation uses a different font with slightly different metrics.

Comment: Yes, @mkl you are right. I checked with internal preview of iReport. I cannot able to reproduce in internal preview. Its perfect in that. But how can I resolve that? Please suggest me.

Comment: I would advice to explicitly set the font, and to do so using both the `fontName` and the `pdfFontName` indicating the same TTF font. This can be done more cleanly using JasperReports font extensions. Cf. [JasperReports - Fonts Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html).

Comment: Hi when I set **pdfFontName="Times-Roman"** then it is same problem. When I set both **pdfFontName="Times-Roman"** and **fontName="Times-Roman"** then I am getting following error : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Times-Roman' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample PDF uses the font Helvetica (supplied by the PDF viewer) which surely is not used by JasperReports when generically pre-compiling the Report.

If different fonts (having different font metrics) are used like this, fields in the output may turn out to be too big or too small. Thus, I'd advice  to explicitly set the font, and to do so using both the `fontName` and the `pdfFontName` attributes indicating the same TTF font. Alternatively this can be done more cleanly using JasperReports font extensions. Cf. [JasperReports - Fonts Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) for details.

### `fontName` and `pdfFontName`

E.g., assuming that you are working in a Windows environment and have the appropriate permissions (otherwise simply adapt the path to point to your copy of the font), you can use Arial like this:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="16" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e4335197-b9f6-4d24-9ea0-ef582bcc8393"/>
    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
        <pen lineColor="#757575"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="none">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="c:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

PDF is a special case in JasperReports because in contrast to most other output formats (which use the system fonts) PDF viewers foremost use one of the standard 14 fonts every PDF viewer must supply or fonts embedded in the respective PDF document; therefore, PDF file generation differs a bit.

### font extensions

The cleaner approach requires you to write a file defining your font families with all relevant information, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Verdana">
        <normal>admin/plugins/ireport/config/fonts/verdana.ttf</normal>
        <bold>admin/plugins/ireport/config/fonts/verdanab.ttf</bold>
        <italic>admin/plugins/ireport/config/fonts/verdanai.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>admin/plugins/ireport/config/fonts/verdanaz.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

(The fonts referenced from that file (verdana*.ttf) are part of the Microsoft "TrueType core fonts for the Web" collection. The license agreement for their use can be found in eula.html which can currently (as of 2011-04-01) be found at http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fontpack/eula.htm.)

Then you need to tell JasperReports font extensions to retrieve its information from that file as described in [the JasperReports font extension sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions), i.e. by providing a `jasperreports_extension.properties` file in the root package containing

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory 
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=my_path/fonts.xml
```

(the pointed-to fonts.xml is the file mentioned above.)

Comment: Hi @mkl Thanks..Its helpful. but can't I provide ttf full filePath in **fontName**'s value same as **pdfFontName**? I am using ubuntu, not Windows. I haven't Arial fonts :(

Comment: Actually I am using font extensions in our production environment, so I'm not sure how exactly JR behaves otherwise (the sample above was a quick hack in iReports). But yes, I would assume you can use full paths there, too. And Arial is just an example.

Comment: no I cannot using fullpath there :( Otherwise it will solve my problem.