# Charts and custom fonts

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, charts, jasper-reports

I have some JasperReports report that uses custom font (Dejavu Serif) which works fine both on development and production machines. Today I added some chart to that report and configured all the font settings to Dejavu Serif. The chart itself works fine but I can't see any labels so I think the problem with custom font.. I found one [post](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534323/reportclassloader-and-font-extensions-issue), but can't understand how they solved the problem..

Update #1:
So I implemented Customizer class which configures the font of labels:

```
public class CustomFontCategoryChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        Font customFont = new Font("DejaVu Serif", Font.BOLD, 12);

        // Works fine
        plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(0.5);
        // Doesn't work
        LegendItemCollection legends = plot.getLegendItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < legends.getItemCount(); i++) {
            legends.get(i).setLabelFont(customFont);
        }
        plot.getLegendItems().addAll(legends);
        // Doesn't work
        LegendItemCollection legends = plot.getLegendItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < legends.getItemCount(); i++) {
            plot.getLegendItems().get(i).setLabelFont(customFont);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything fine except of legend labels.. Can't make it work with custom font.. Any help?

Comment: got through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179664/how-to-remove-unnecessary-wrapping-in-pdf-generated-using-jasperreports-jrxml

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia can't understand how it helps? My issue that somehow charts can't see the custom fonts, in other reports fonts work perfectly

Comment: You can add font using customizer class. It will work perfectly in chart.

Comment: @user1791574 Works fine with the labels but can't change legend's labels...

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered, so I'll dot it by myself...
In order to use custom fonts in JasperReports's charts you should do the following:

1. Overload the JRChartCustomizer's `customize` method as showed:

   ```
   public class CustomFontCategoryChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer  {
       @Override
       public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
           Font customFont = new Font("DejaVu Serif", Font.PLAIN, 9);
           CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

           // Set legend's font        
           chart.getLegend().setItemFont(customFont);
           // Set categories label's font
           plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
           // Set amounts label's font 
           plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add reference to iReport to your `JRChartCustomizer` implementation or to jar file
3. Configure `Customizer Class` option inside iReport's chart object with apapropriate class name. In my case with `CustomFontCategoryChartCustomizer`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomFontCategoryChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer  {
@Override
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    Font customFont = getOpenSansFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

    // Set legend's font        
    chart.getLegend().setItemFont(customFont);
    // Set categories label's font
    plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
    // Set amounts label's font 
    plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(customFont);
  }

 private Font getOpenSansFont(String ttfFont) {
    try {
        String openSansAbsolutePath = "absolute/path/to/font"
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(openSansAbsolutePath));
        return font.deriveFont(10f);
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
        println "Exception occur during create font." + e
    }
  }
}
```

You need to put ttf font in you application class path. It worked perfectly for me. I had used it one of my project.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'll try it.. I found a lot of articles where it is possible to get the font directly from resources.. once again locally works fine, but at production the text is invisible.. Without any exceptions.. Strange!

Comment: @nKognito Did you try this?