# no space required between detail in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the following problem. I need in my report, it does not automatically add a space between the details:

[image: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140725013402565313.png]

This is the view from my template:

[image: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140725013404794353.png]

Comment: Is your final output to PDF? It looks like you have different fonts there. Most likely your font setup is faulty.

Comment: For details on more complete font setup, especially in the context of PDF output, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23312287/1729265).